# using newInstance to create objects

Tags: java, factory

I am doing some exercises from the book *Thinking In Java*.  I have some problems with one exercise.  It says:

> A constructor is a kind of factory method. Modify RegisteredFactories.java so that instead of using an explicit factory, the class object is stored in the List, and newInstance( ) is used to create each object.

How can I achieve that?  Below is code for factory interface and RegisteredFactories class.  Thank you

```
package typeinfo.factory;    
public interface Factory<T> { T create(); } ///:~
package cont;

import typeinfo.factory.*;
import java.util.*;


class Part {

  public String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  static List<Factory<? extends Part>> partFactories =
    new ArrayList<Factory<? extends Part>>();     

  static {
    // Collections.addAll() gives an "unchecked generic
    // array creation ... for varargs parameter" warning.
    partFactories.add(new FuelFilter.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new AirFilter.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new CabinAirFilter.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new OilFilter.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new FanBelt.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new PowerSteeringBelt.Factory());
    partFactories.add(new GeneratorBelt.Factory());
  }

  private static Random rand = new Random(47);
  public static Part createRandom() {
    int n = rand.nextInt(partFactories.size());
    return partFactories.get(n).create();
  }
}

class Filter extends Part {}

class FuelFilter extends Filter {
  // Create a Class Factory for each specific type:
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<FuelFilter> {
    public FuelFilter create() { return new FuelFilter(); }
  }
}

class AirFilter extends Filter {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<AirFilter> {
    public AirFilter create() { return new AirFilter(); }
  }
} 

class CabinAirFilter extends Filter {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<CabinAirFilter> {
    public CabinAirFilter create() {
      return new CabinAirFilter();
    }
  }
}

class OilFilter extends Filter {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<OilFilter> {
    public OilFilter create() { return new OilFilter(); }
  }
} 

class Belt extends Part {}

class FanBelt extends Belt {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<FanBelt> {
    public FanBelt create() { return new FanBelt(); }
  }
}

class GeneratorBelt extends Belt {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<GeneratorBelt> {
    public GeneratorBelt create() {
      return new GeneratorBelt();
    }
  }
} 

class PowerSteeringBelt extends Belt {
  public static class Factory
  implements typeinfo.factory.Factory<PowerSteeringBelt> {
    public PowerSteeringBelt create() {
      return new PowerSteeringBelt();
    }
  }
} 

public class RegisteredFactories {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      System.out.println(Part.createRandom());
  }
}
```

Comment: "The class object is stored in the List". Which List?

Comment: This is the exact question from the book, a bit confusing.  I assume that either it is any List (but then why author used The) or the List already used in RegisteredFactories class.

Comment: ok I will do it more diligently from now on.  It is hard to go back to each question I have asked in the past

Comment: @aretai: How is it hard? Here's the complete list of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1124682/aretai?tab=questions

Comment: Only to questions. You can see your past questions from your [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1124682/aretai?tab=questions)

Comment: am relatively new so it may be hard for me. Funny just tried to use up arrow for one question and it says it is now locked

Comment: Ok will do that but plz answer my question as I think you guys focus on something that may be important but not a part of my question.

Comment: @aretai you are right that it's not relevant, but first understand that accept is not an "upvote" - it is the V that's below it. you can choose only one answer as the "accepted" answer - it provides the recognition that this answer was the most helpful. people are putting time and effort to answer your questions - so you should be polite enough to take the 0.5 second it takes to click the V and choose the best answer.

Comment: Oic so it is not upvote.  Well am still learning this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here:

```
import java.util.*;

class Part {

  public String toString() {

    return getClass().getSimpleName();

  }

  static List<Class> partFactories = new ArrayList<Class>();

  static {

    // Collections.addAll() gives an "unchecked generic

    // array creation ... for varargs parameter" warning.

    partFactories.add(FuelFilter.class);

    partFactories.add(AirFilter.class);

    partFactories.add(CabinAirFilter.class);

    partFactories.add(OilFilter.class);

    partFactories.add(FanBelt.class);

    partFactories.add(PowerSteeringBelt.class);

    partFactories.add(GeneratorBelt.class);
  }


  private static Random rand = new Random(47);

  public static Part createRandom() throws Exception {

    int n = rand.nextInt(partFactories.size());

    return (Part)(partFactories.get(n).newInstance());

  }

}



class Filter extends Part {}

class FuelFilter extends Filter {
}
class AirFilter extends Filter {
}
class CabinAirFilter extends Filter {
}
class OilFilter extends Filter {
}
class Belt extends Part {}
class FanBelt extends Belt {
}
class GeneratorBelt extends Belt {
}
class PowerSteeringBelt extends Belt {
}



public class aa{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

      try {System.out.println(Part.createRandom()); }catch (Exception e) {}

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`static List<Factory<? extends Part>> partFactories`
thats the list,
it contains several factories and is initiated in the static block.  
this code randomly creates objects via their factories using createRandom method 

the idea is that instead of creating an object by calling new, you create one using its factory
all factories here implement the interface Factory, which means they have a method called create()
 that returns a new instance of the desired class (the one the factory belongs to)

Comment: Ok so if that is the list author is talking about.  How should I change the code to meet the question's criteria?

Comment: this is what you put in the list: PowerSteeringBelt.class; when you go over the list to create instances you call partFactories.get(n).getClass().newInstance(); and you can remove all the factory related code

Comment: I tried to do that.  As I understand I need first to redefine list to   static List<? extends Part> partFactories = new ArrayList<? extends Part>(); //however compiler doesn't allow that.  After that I need to change partFactories.add(new PowerSteeringBelt.Factory()); into partFactories.add(PowerSteeringBelt.class); how to fix it then?

Comment: change the list to: static List<Class> partFactories = new ArrayList<Class>(); after that change the create line to this: return (Part)(partFactories.get(n).newInstance()); also the adding to the list should look like this: partFactories.add(FuelFilter.class);

Comment: It seems that everything is working just fine except return statement as it has to deal with IllegalAccessException.  I tried to have it in try-catch but then whole method says it needs to return Part1 (changed Part to Part1):  public static Part1 createRandom() {

    int n = rand.nextInt(partFactories1.size());

    //return partFactories1.get(n).create();
    //return (Part1)(partFactories1.get(n).newInstance());
    try {
     return (Part1) (partFactories1.get(n).newInstance());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    

  }

Comment: @aretai if it's a new question - post a new one. If you want to extend this question please post the code in the question - it's very difficult to read code from a comment.